# Shinyjs hide and show not properly working

Tags: shiny, show-hide, shinyjs

I have a problem with shinyjs hide() and show(). I use this to hide and show different data anyalysis that can be choosen from a side bar.
If I do one part of my code it works fine but when I hide() and then do a different calculation it shows me the text part of the firt one again.
Does anyone has any idea oder experienced similar things?

I expect my code to hide/delete the part I did not want to see anymore and just showing me the new analysis I choosed.

Thanks and best,
Marina

Here´s my code from UI:

```
tabPanel(title="Datenanalyse",value="analysis",
                              includeMarkdown("../Texte/Mietpreise/Datenanalyse.md"),
                              fluidPage(
                                sidebarLayout(
                                  sidebarPanel(
                                    uiOutput("variables"),
                                    
                                    selectInput("methods","Analysemethode",choices= c("Boxplot"="box","Balkendiagramm"="balken",
                                                                                      "Histogramm"="hist","Streudiagramm"="streu",
                                                                                      "Kreisdiagramm"="kreis",
                                                                                      "arithm. Mittel"="mw","N(%)"="anz","Regression"="reg"),
                                                selected="box"),
                                    actionButton("vorschau","Vorschau"),
                                    actionButton("clear","Löschen"),
                                    actionButton("fest","Festsetzen"),
                                    hr(),
                                    br(),
                                    br(),
                                    br(),
                                    br(),
                                    actionButton("zurueck3","Zurück"),
                                    actionButton("hilfe3", "Hilfe"),
                                    actionButton("weiter4","Weiter")
                                  ),
                                  
                                  mainPanel(
                                    textOutput("txt"),
                                    textOutput("txt3"),
                                    uiOutput("createvars"),
                                    tableOutput("txt2"),
                                    plotOutput("plot")
                                    
                                  )
                                )
                              )
                     )
```

And here´s the part from server:

```
 observeEvent(input$clear,{
  shinyjs::hide("plot")
  shinyjs::hide("txt")
  shinyjs::hide("txt2")
  shinyjs::hide("txt3")
  shinyjs::hide("createvars")
})
observeEvent(input$vorschau,{
  shinyjs::show("plot")
  shinyjs::show("txt")
  shinyjs::show("txt2")
  shinyjs::show("createvars")
  shinyjs::show("txt3")
  
})
 observeEvent(input$vorschau,{
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    if(input$methods =="box"){
      if(length(input$variables==1)){
        p <- boxplot(x = d()[input$variables],xlab=input$variables)
      }
      if(length(input$variables)>1){
        p <- boxplot(x = d()[input$variables])
      }
    }
    if(input$methods =="balken"){
      p <- barplot(table(d()[input$variables]),xlab=input$variables)
    }
    if(input$methods =="hist"){
      p <- hist(as.numeric(unlist(d()[input$variables])),xlab=input$variables, ylab="Anzahl", main="")
    }
    if(input$methods =="streu"){
      p <- plot(d()[input$variables])
    }
    if(input$methods =="kreis"){
      p <- pie(table(d()[input$variables]),main = input$variables)
    }
    
  })
  output$txt <- renderText({
    
    if(input$methods =="mw"){
      paste0("Das arithmetische Mittel von ",input$variables," beträgt: ", round(mean(as.numeric(unlist(d()[input$variables]))),2))
    }
  })
  
  output$txt2 <- renderTable({
    if(input$methods =="anz"){
      t<-data.frame(table(d()[input$variables]))
      col_headings <- c(paste0(input$variables),"Freq")
      colnames(t)<-col_headings
      t
    }
  })
  if(input$methods =="reg"){
    output$txt3 <- renderText({
      paste0("Geben Sie zuerst die Einflussgröße und dann die Zielgröße im Feld Variablenauswahl an.")
    })

    output$plot<-renderPlot({
      lmodel <- lm(as.numeric(unlist(d()[input$variables][2]))~as.numeric(unlist(d()[input$variables][1])))
      plot(d()[input$variables],xlab = names(d()[input$variables][1]),
           ylab=names(d()[input$variables][2]), main= paste(names(d()[input$variables][2]),' =', round(coef(lmodel)[[2]],2), ' * ', names(d()[input$variables][1]), '+', round(coef(lmodel)[[1]],2)))
      abline(lmodel)
    })
  }
  
})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code as a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that someone can help to identify the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.